# remove empty line brakes in Excel

Tags: excel

How to remove empty lines in excel document?

My  data is:

[image]

I want to get these result:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voted for close, because there is no connection to programming.

Comment: Nope this can be achieved through VBA so there is a connection

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. highlight your data
2. Go to the "Home" Tab.
3. Click "Find and Select" (all the way to the right)
4. Click "Go to Special"
5. Select "Blanks" and hit "OK"
6. Right click, Delete Rows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this quickly you can

1.Select the range containing blank rows you want to remove.

2.Click Home > Find & Select > Go To Special.

[image]

3.In the Go To Special dialog box, check the Blanks option.

[image]

4. And then click OK, all of the entire blank rows are highlighted. Then click Home > Delete > Delete Sheet Rows,

And you are done

A quick VBA function can also handle that

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Remove blank rows from excel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
xRows = WorkRng.Rows.Count
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = xRows To 1 Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WorkRng.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
        WorkRng.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Moreover, if you want to make your job easier you can try kutools and then you can remove blank rows in one click https://www.extendoffice.com/download/kutools-for-excel.html

[image]